# Leaflet.Control.Layers.Tree - Expand/Collapse Childrens

Tags: javascript

How can we **Expand/Collapse** any Entries in the List

I use the Leaflet.Control.Layers.Tree Plugin

[This is a TreePreview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51V6C.jpg)

'Tanken' is parent with checkbox - then 3 children with radiogroups

How to:

- parent 'Tanken' set settings **collapse/expand** by defalut
- if parent click checked then show the ParentMarkersEntries and unchecked all children and remove the ChildrenMarkerEntrie
- if parent click unchecked then remove ParentMarkersEntries and unchecked all children and ChildrenMarkerEntrie
- if click a Children checked make parent unchecked and ParentMarkersEntries

```js
/* Show no BaseLayers
var baseTree = {
    label: 'BaseLayers',
    noShow: true,
    children: [{
        label: 'OpenStreeMap',
        layer: osm,
        children: [{ label: 'B&W', layer: osm, name: 'OpenStreeMap B&W'}]
       }]
};
*/

var ctl = L.control.layers.tree(null, null,{
    collapsed: false,
    namedToggle: true,
    collapseAll: '',
    expandAll: '',
});

/*Add Control to Map*/
ctl.addTo(map).collapseTree().expandSelected();

/*Set TreeList*/
var tanken = new L.LayerGroup();
    tanken1 = L.marker([51.466399, 13.868011],{icon: greenIcon, bounceOnAdd: true, bounceOnAddOptions: {duration: 500, height: 100}}).bindPopup('TOTAL Tankstelle').addTo(tanken);
    tanken2 = L.marker([51.470673, 13.868942],{icon: greenIcon, bounceOnAdd: true}).bindPopup('SHELL Tankstelle').addTo(tanken);
    tanken3 = L.marker([51.476386, 13.899422],{icon: greenIcon, bounceOnAdd: true}).bindPopup('STAR Tankstelle').addTo(tanken);   

var parking = new L.LayerGroup();
    L.marker([51.47788, 13.90316],{icon: blueIcon, bounceOnAdd: true}).bindPopup('Schwarzheide Ost - Ernst Thälmann Strasse').addTo(parking);
    L.marker([51.47633, 13.89933],{icon: blueIcon, bounceOnAdd: true}).bindPopup('Schwarzheide Ost - START Tankstelle').addTo(parking);
    L.marker([51.47349, 13.89599],{icon: blueIcon, bounceOnAdd: true}).bindPopup('Schwarzheide Ost - Friedhof Ost').addTo(parking);
    … many more

var … many more

/*Set Overlays*/
var overlayTree = [
    {label: 'Übersicht'},
    {label: 'Verkehr', children: [
        {label: 'Tanken', layer: tanken, children: [
            {label: 'TOTAL Tankstelle', layer: tanken1, radioGroup: 'streets'},
            {label: 'SHELL Tankstelle', layer: tanken2, radioGroup: 'streets'},
            {label: 'STAR Tankstelle', layer: tanken3, radioGroup: 'streets'},          
        ]},
        {label: 'Parken', layer: parking},
        {label: 'Bus', layer: bus},
        {label: 'Bahn', layer: bahn},               
    ]},
    … many more
];

/*Set Option to Overlays*/
/*This Option Expand/Collaps complete OverlayTree*/
var ctl = L.control.layers.tree(null, null,{
    collapsed: false,
    namedToggle: true,
    collapseAll: '',
    expandAll: '',
});

/*Add Overlay to Control*/
ctl.setOverlayTree(overlayTree).collapseTree(false).expandSelected(true);
```

I hope you can understand me, sorry for my English

When I add "radioGroup: 'streets'," to Parent 'Tanken'

```
var overlayTree = [
{label: 'Übersicht'},
{label: 'Verkehr', children: [
    {label: 'Tanken', layer: tanken, radioGroup: 'streets', children: [
        {label: 'TOTAL Tankstelle', layer: tanken1, radioGroup: 'streets'},
        {label: 'SHELL Tankstelle', layer: tanken2, radioGroup: 'streets'},
        {label: 'STAR Tankstelle', layer: tanken3, radioGroup: 'streets'},          
    ]},
```

then the Parent Object has no Checkbox,the click Function is ok.

I want The Parent to have a Checkbox with Radiogroup Function

Comment: add the html as well

Comment: here is no html
<div id'map'></div>

then js

Comment: how we can add a Image?

Comment: Click on picture in the post edit place then click on browse

Answer (score 0):

I Found this:

```
$(".chb").change(function() {
$(".chb").prop('checked', false);
$(this).prop('checked', true);});
```

This works fine.

How we cann add this in Leaflet.Control.Layers.Tree  or in my Code ???

The Button are createt in Leaflet.Control.Layers.Tree  at Line367

```
           ...// create the input and label, as in Control.Layers
        var label = creator(tree.layer ? 'label' : 'span', this.cls.label, entry);
        if (tree.layer) {
            // now create the element like in _addItem
            var checked = this._map.hasLayer(tree.layer)
            var input 
            var radioGroup = overlay ? tree.radioGroup : 'leaflet-base-layers_' + L.Util.stamp(this);
            //
            if (radioGroup) {
                input = this._createRadioElement(radioGroup, checked);
            } else {
                input = this._createCheckboxElement(checked);
            }
            if (this._layerControlInputs) {
                // to keep compatibility with 1.0.3
                this._layerControlInputs.push(input);
            }
            input.layerId = L.Util.stamp(tree.layer);
            L.DomEvent.on(input, 'click', this._onInputClick, this);
            label.appendChild(input);               
        }...
```

Comment: where does .chb come from? when will it be triggered?

Did the same in my project but nothing happens.